# How many triggers can be created on a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Is there a limit? How many triggers can be created on a single table in SQL Server?

Also is this limit changed in SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008 and 2012.

Also there are two types of triggers `INSTEAD OF` triggers and `For/After` triggers. What is the limit on them separately?

Comment: I'm scared to ask _why_ you need this.

Comment: `Instead of` Trigger is one per action type

Comment: That is just out of curiosity Oded. Giving Negative reputation to the question does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Limited by number of total objects in database.  The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647

In other words, you don't have to be concerned about this limit; you'll never hit it under *ordinary* circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Robert - can you add a link of MSDN or SQL server manual where it is specified.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx.  It was the first match to a Google Search for "SQL Server Limits".  Google is an excellent resource; you should try it sometime. :)

Comment: Thank you Robert for the link. It will help.